# SQL union query not returning both columns

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to retrieve data from a database in a particular format to hook into a dashboard app. I need one column called "Import" with counts beneath it, and another called "Export" with relevant counts in that. I have the following query right now but it is only returning an Import column and I've verified there is relevant data to show as Export as well. Any ideas?  Adding a screenshot of the result I'm getting...

[image]

```
SELECT count(*) as "Import", a.ship_id "Ship"
  FROM  SERVICE_EVENTS a JOIN CONTAINERS b ON a.eq_nbr = b.nbr
 WHERE  (
        (to_char(sysdate, 'HH24') between '07' and '17' and a.performed between trunc(sysdate) + 7/24 and sysdate and category = 'I')
        OR
        (to_char(sysdate, 'HH24') between '18' and '23' and a.performed between trunc(sysdate) + 18/24 and sysdate and category = 'I')
        OR
        (to_char(sysdate, 'HH24') between '00' and '06' and a.performed between trunc(sysdate - 1) + 18/24 and sysdate and category = 'I')
        )
        AND a.TSERV_ID in ('LOAD', 'DISCHARGE') group by a.ship_id 
UNION
SELECT count(*) as "Export", a.ship_id "Ship"
  FROM  SERVICE_EVENTS a JOIN CONTAINERS b ON a.eq_nbr = b.nbr
 WHERE  (
        (to_char(sysdate, 'HH24') between '07' and '17' and a.performed between trunc(sysdate) + 7/24 and sysdate and category = 'E')
        OR
        (to_char(sysdate, 'HH24') between '18' and '23' and a.performed between trunc(sysdate) + 18/24 and sysdate and category = 'E')
        OR
        (to_char(sysdate, 'HH24') between '00' and '06' and a.performed between trunc(sysdate - 1) + 18/24 and sysdate and category = 'E')
        )
        AND a.TSERV_ID in ('LOAD', 'DISCHARGE') group by a.ship_id 

;
```

Comment: What would be your expected result?

Comment: a UNION does not add the extra data as columns (to the right), it adds extra rows to the result (in the existing columns). You could separate the two by adding another column "type" (otherwise it may be hard to tell them apart) or do something more involved like @vkp does in his answer.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a conditional aggregation and simplify your query to this:

```
SELECT
    a.ship_id AS Ship,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN category = 'I' THEN 1 END) AS Import,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN category = 'E' THEN 1 END) AS Export
FROM SERVICE_EVENTS a 
JOIN CONTAINERS b 
    ON a.eq_nbr = b.nbr
WHERE
    (
        (to_char(sysdate, 'HH24') BETWEEN '07' AND '17' AND a.performed BETWEEN trunc(sysdate) + 7/24 AND sysdate)      
        OR (to_char(sysdate, 'HH24') BETWEEN '18' AND '23' AND a.performed BETWEEN trunc(sysdate) + 18/24 AND sysdate)
        OR (to_char(sysdate, 'HH24') BETWEEN '00' AND '06' AND a.performed BETWEEN trunc(sysdate - 1) + 18/24 AND sysdate)
    )
    AND a.TSERV_ID in ('LOAD', 'DISCHARGE')
GROUP BY a.ship_id
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm and looks so much cleaner.

Comment: @runelynx I made an edit, make sure to test it again.

Comment: Thanks, caught that... first run forced category to 'E' :-)  Will run your new version through though.

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly select `null` as the column not being counted and do one more aggregation.

```
select max(Import) as Import, max(Export) as Export, Ship
from (  
SELECT count(*) as "Import", null as "Export", a.ship_id "Ship"
  FROM  SERVICE_EVENTS a JOIN CONTAINERS b ON a.eq_nbr = b.nbr
 WHERE  (
        (to_char(sysdate, 'HH24') between '07' and '17' and a.performed between trunc(sysdate) + 7/24 and sysdate and category = 'I')
        OR
        (to_char(sysdate, 'HH24') between '18' and '23' and a.performed between trunc(sysdate) + 18/24 and sysdate and category = 'I')
        OR
        (to_char(sysdate, 'HH24') between '00' and '06' and a.performed between trunc(sysdate - 1) + 18/24 and sysdate and category = 'I')
        )
        AND a.TSERV_ID in ('LOAD', 'DISCHARGE') group by a.ship_id 
UNION
SELECT null as import, count(*) as "Export", a.ship_id "Ship"
  FROM  SERVICE_EVENTS a JOIN CONTAINERS b ON a.eq_nbr = b.nbr
 WHERE  (
        (to_char(sysdate, 'HH24') between '07' and '17' and a.performed between trunc(sysdate) + 7/24 and sysdate and category = 'E')
        OR
        (to_char(sysdate, 'HH24') between '18' and '23' and a.performed between trunc(sysdate) + 18/24 and sysdate and category = 'E')
        OR
        (to_char(sysdate, 'HH24') between '00' and '06' and a.performed between trunc(sysdate - 1) + 18/24 and sysdate and category = 'E')
        )
        AND a.TSERV_ID in ('LOAD', 'DISCHARGE') group by a.ship_id 
  ) t
group by Ship
```